# fetch solo funciona desde el pc no desde el movil

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

fetch en el pc me funciona perfectamente recibo y pinto los datos que traigo de la API pero desde el móvil no. Alguna idea? Os dejo el proyecto.

https://davidjimenezwd.github.io/react-weatherapp/

https://github.com/DavidJimenezWD/react-weatherapp

Comment: Bienvenido, te sugerimos agrar lo que trataste o investigaste en tu pregunta, revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta agregando más información, saludos.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta es muy simple, en tu frontend osea en react en tu caso cambia el ENDPOINT de ***http://localhost:3000 ---> http://192.168.1.100:3000*** (192.168.1.100 es mi ip donde esta funcionando mi backend)

Comment: Se te olvidó mencionar que esa es la IP que tu tienes y que se debería reemplazar por la correspondiente. Sería casualidad que dicha IP sea la misma a la tuya.

Comment: La IP debe reemplazarse por la ip de su pc donde esta desarrollando el proyecto porsupuesto.